# roslaunch if condition

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can say: run this node if argX==y

The following does not work, and the documentation on this is lacking.

```
<node pkg="xxx" type="yyy" name="yyy" if="$(arg argX)==y" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12756/roslaunch-if-condition/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this now in ROS Kinetic using `eval`:

```
<arg name="arg_name" default="desired_value"/>

<node pkg="node_pkg" type="node_type" name="node_name" 
      if="$(eval arg('arg_name') == 'desired_value')"/>
```

The documentation has been updated: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 34

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [limitless](https://answers.ros.org/users/32845/limitless/) on 2017-12-02**:

```
  <group if="$(eval arg('debug') ==0)">
    <node pkg="xxx" type="yyy" name="yyy">
  </group>
```

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2019-03-15**:

worked for me. The above did not work for me.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-05-25**:
Updated the answer's description based on @limitless and @Markus' comments.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation on the roslaunch page for this syntax is complete, i.e. you can't do comparisons or any operators for that matter.  You can only test the value itself.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-10**:
link to the documentation --- http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this answer still current? I see that xacro got an upgrade: from http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Conditional_Blocks
"The more powerful evaluation capabilities in ROS Jade allow for much more complex expression. Virtually any python expression that evaluates to a Boolean is feasible."

EDIT 2015.6.30:

I found a [related ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/503) suggesting that Ken's answer is probably still current, though I don't yet have jade to check for sure.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is supported as of ROS Kinetic.

```
<group if="$(arg foo)">
  <!-- stuff that will only be evaluated if foo is true -->
</group>
```

See also http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML

---

Originally posted by [toblech](https://answers.ros.org/users/27825/toblech/) with karma: 86 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-01-31**:
This does not answer the question which is about comparing `foo` to some arbitrary (non-bool) value.